# Javascript contador

Tags: javascript

Tenho um formulário em pdf que ja tem um javascript que se for inserido um valor diferente do pré determinado a fonte fica vermelha, e se for dentro dos limites determinado a fonte fica verde.

Gostaria de inserir três campos de contadores, um com o número de campos em vermelho e o outro com o número de campos em verde, e um terceiro campo com o numero total de campos (verde + vermelho). Têm como fazer isso ?

Código que eu uso para fazer a coloração.

```
var v = Number(event.value);
  if (v>=10.720 && v<=10.780)
    event.target.textColor = color.green;
  else event.target.textColor = color.red;
```

Comment: Artur, ter tem. Mas ficaria mais fácil te ajudar se postar seu código (html e js).

Comment: formulário em pdf? Como seria isso? Novidade pra mim.

Comment: Diego, o código que eu uso é esse aqui:  

var v = Number(event.value);

if (v>=10.720 && v<=10.780) event.target.textColor = color.green;

else event.target.textColor = color.red;

então precisava criar um código novo para contar a quantidade de campos em vermelho e a quantidade de campos em verde.

Comment: @Artur edite e pergunta com o seu código. Vou colocar ele pra você, mas faça isso nas próximas vezes.